# Binary search of an ArrayList object method to retrieve a string will not identify if strings are identical?

Tags: string, collections, arraylist, binary-search

The program in it's entirety sorts an `ArrayList` of `Student` objects by integers highest average, last name, and also has the option to perform a search. My program works flawlessly except for my binary search, for which I can absolutely not determine the cause of failure. I have printed all the information as it comes up.

Here is the student class with the method that references the Student's first and last name (`String`).

```
   public String getFirstName (){
      return firstname;
   }

   public String getLastName(){
      return lastname;
   }
```

In addition, here is the code for the binary search. Yes, I know `Collections` has a method for this exact purpose, but for my class I need to write up the search myself.

```
private static void searchStudent(ArrayList<Student> a){
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter search term: ");
             String term = reader.next();

    //System.out.println(term + " " + term.length());
    System.out.println("---SEARCH RESULTS:---");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        String fName = (a.get(i).getFirstName());
        String lName = (a.get(i).getLastName());
        //System.out.println(fName + " " + fName.length());
        //System.out.println(lName + " " + lName.length());
            if (term == fName){
                System.out.println(a.get(i));
            } else if (term == lName){
                System.out.println(a.get(i));
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Java, you need to use `.equals()` to compare strings. E.g. instead of this:

```
if (term == fName){
```

you need to do this:

```
if (term.equals(fName)){
```

Otherwise, you are comparing references only.

Btw, this is not a binary search, it's a linear search. You can see one implementation of binary search e.g. here:

- http://leepoint.net/notes-java/algorithms/searching/binarysearch.html

though to compare strings you would use [.compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) / [.compareToIgnoreCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) methods on the String class instead of `<` / `>` operators.